# Why are these imagesearches giving me random/wrong errorlevels?

Tags: autohotkey

The below is part of my debugging/problem.  I'm running multiple imagesearch's one after another and I guess there is an issue with that because for all I can tell both of these instances should output found, but the second one outputs Didn't find.  Then all of a sudden sometimes it will find both:

```
#SingleInstance Force

WinActivate, Microsoft Solitaire Collection ahk_class ApplicationFrameWindow

x1 = 699
x2 = 739
y1 = 473
y2 = 528

ImageSearch, X, Y, x1, y1, x2, y2, deck\5d.png
        if ErrorLevel = 2
            {

            }
        else if ErrorLevel = 1
            {
                Msgbox, Didnt Find
            }
        else 
            {
                ;found
                MsgBox Found
            }       
ImageSearch, X, Y, x1, y1, x2, y2, deck\5d.png
        if ErrorLevel = 2
            {

            }
        else if ErrorLevel = 1
            {
                Msgbox, Didnt Find
            }
        else 
            {
                ;found
                MsgBox Found
            }
```

Comment: I changed it so the error outputs are Didn't find 1, Found 1, Didn't Find 2, Found 2 respectively and the msgbox's say Found 1 and Didn't find 2.

Comment: If i sleep for 3000 the 2nd instance outputs Found2

Comment: testing suggests that it takes 'sleep 200' approximately to reset the error levels. Make sense?

Comment: seems to work fine when i remove my error msgboxes.  I guess that makes sense such errors are supposed to halt further action?

Comment: been messing around with better results with the variation at *200

Comment: starting to feel like this is purposeful design for anti cheating, although its just solitaire. There is a threshold where image search will identify newly rendered cards but then it confuses the suits and the 2 thresholds seem to overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the *variation* parameter:

```
ImageSearch X, Y, x1, y1, x2, y2, *32 deck\5d.png
                                  ^^^
```

Sometimes images are subtlely altered each time they are rendered

Comment: Thank you, I am going to play with that parameter and learn about it, however I don't think that is the problem.  It just seems that way the way that its all worded etc.  

I tried that and it still doesn't work.

I think its about the error codes not resetting or something...basically I am now getting 'found' and then 'not found' even with the added parameter.

Comment: There's a time delay between the two searches.  It maybe that the image has been re-rendered by the time the second search triggers.  Are you searching for a moving graphic?  Some rendering engines might, for example, render the graphic pixel-perfect if it's position is (10,10), but apply interpolation when rendering at (10.5,10.5).

Comment: Sometimes I screen capture a graphic several times to get a variety of renderings. Then I search for each captured image before deciding it's not found.

Comment: Ok thanks, gives me hope. I've been all through this and keep wanting to blame it on a sophisticated anti-cheating thing (for solitaire ;p). I supposed ill try getting a few shots and seeing what my probability of finding becomes. Thanks!

Comment: I also try to keep the search image as small as possible and still be unique enough to positively identify the graphic I'm searching for

Comment: Yes thanks over the course of days I created a rigorous proof for that realization ;p